# Creating a Class in Perl

Tags: perl, oop

```
package Person;
sub new
{
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {
        _firstName => shift,
        _lastName  => shift,
        _ssn       => shift,
    };
    # Print all the values just for clarification.
    print "First Name is $self->{_firstName}\n";
    print "Last Name is $self->{_lastName}\n";
    print "SSN is $self->{_ssn}\n";
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}
```

I got the above code from this [site](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_oo_perl.htm).

From the official Perl site on Classes:

> Perl does not provide any special syntax for class definitions. A
>   package is simply a namespace containing variables and subroutines.

1. With that in mind, is the above code from Tutorial Point, the proper best practice when creating a class in Perl?
2. In other OO languages you can throw exceptions from inside the constructor when a value is not set, could do you this as well inside Perl?
3. Which is the proper way to bless?

The code in tutorial point does this:

```
bless $self, $class;
```

But from the perl documentation:

```
  my $self = bless {
      path => $path,
      data => $data,
  }, $class;
  return $self;
```

Comment: The Tutorial Point tutorial you linked to makes no mention of strict or warnings, at least in the first 8 pages or so that I skimmed through. That makes it a bad tutorial. Run far away! Here's a list of [more modern tutorials](http://perl-tutorial.org/).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - That page you linked to said that tutorialpoint shouldn't be trusted

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - I guess the perl documentation from the official site is the best way to go then.

Comment: Have you seen [perlootut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html)? It's the official tutorial on Perl OO (part of the official documentation). If you have perldoc installed on your system, you can view it by running `perldoc perlootut`.

Comment: The two methods of `bless`-ing are equivalent. Perl has enough syntax to make it possible to do the same thing 100 different ways. See: [TMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. With that in mind, is the above code from Tutorial Point, the proper
>      best practice when creating a class in Perl?

There is nothing inherently wrong with the code from Tutorial Point. It creates a perfectly adequate class. However, as others have pointed out, the Tutorial Point site is not highly regarded and you would be well advised to look elsewhere for better tutorials.

> 2. In other OO languages you can throw exceptions from inside the
>      constructor when a value is not set, could do you this as well
>      inside Perl?

In Perl code, you throw an exception by calling [`die()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html). You catch an exception using [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) and looking at the value of `$@`. Modules like [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try::Tiny) can make this process look more like other languages.

> 3. Which is the proper way to bless?

The Perl slogan is "There's More Than One Way To Do It". Both of your code examples do the same thing. The only reasons to choose one over the other would be personal preference and in-house style.

However, many Perl programmers have moved away from this style of OO programming and are, instead, using [Moose](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose) (or its cut-down relation [Moo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo)) for all of their OO code. You may well find that looking at these options makes your life easier.

Answer (score 5):

Perl doesn't have object constructors. `new` is just a method like any other, and methods can throw exceptions.

---

`bless` returns its first argument, so

```
bless($ref, $class);
return $ref;
```

and

```
return bless($ref, $class);
```

are equivalent. Both are proper.

---

Personally, I create the object first, then add to it. This creates a parallel between the constructor in the base class

```
sub new {
   my ($class, ...) = @_;
   my $self = bless({}, $class);
   $self->{...} = ...;
   return $self;
}
```

and constructors in child classes

```
sub new {
   my ($class, ...) = @_;
   my $self = $class->SUPER::new(...);
   $self->{...} = ...;
   return $self;
}
```

But that's just my personal preference.

Comment: What about the other 2/3 of the question?

Comment: @Matt Jacob, What's the best way of doing two equivalent things? They're equivalent!

Comment: No, points 1 and 2: best practices for creating classes, and throwing exceptions from the constructor.

Comment: 1 and 3) As I just said, there's no best way of doing two equivalent things. 2) I missed that one. Added to answer.

Comment: Ehhh... are 1 and 3 the same thing? I don't really think so. `bless` creates objects, but people create classes.